# One-sided derivative at the boundary of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Suppose we are solving the Sturm-Liouville problem $$y'' + \lambda y = 0$$ on some interval $x \in [a,b]$. Now, since $a$ and $b$ are the boundaries of the interval, we cannot define the usual derivatives $y'$ and $y''$ there, only the one-sided derivatives. Therefore, I believe that the ODE should be restricted to the open interval $(a,b)$ and the solution should be extended to the boundary points via continuity. However, I have never seen this explicitly stated. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It is correct, but...: simply consider it on $\mathbb R$ and solve it there (this is usual rigorous approach).

Comment: @John B: can this always be done?

Comment: It can't. Sure, the theorems are usually formulated for open sets, but it doesn't mean that some results cannot be extended to closed set with appropriate conditions. On the other hand, it is simpler (if possible in some specific problem) to think of a larger open set.

Comment: Alternatively, you could assume that $\lim y'$ exists at the endpoints. In some sense, that is a better fit because of integral formulations used to solve the ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common with equations of this type to study the equation in $L^2(0,1)$. For example, consider $Lf=-f''$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ consisting of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f : (0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $f,Lf$ are square integrable on $(0,1)$. You have to be a bit careful in talking about the functions as having pointwise limits, but it makes sense because there can be at most one continuous function in the equivalence class for $f$, $f'$. Because $f'' \in L^2$, then the following has limits as $a\downarrow 0$ and $b\uparrow 1$:
$$
        \int_{a}^{b}f''(t)dt
$$
So there is a natural and unique way to define $f'(a),f'(b)$ as limits of $f'$ as you near the endpoints. Likewise, there is a unique way to define $f(a)$, $f(b)$ as limits of $f$ as you near the endpoints.

The existence of endpoint values for $f,f'$ are deduced from knowing properties of $f\in\mathcal{D}(L)$ in $(a,b)$. So your suspicions about how the property should be formulated coincide with the conventions adopted to deal with ODEs in the setting of $L^2$. The endpoint values are defined through the set of linear functionals $\Phi$ that are continuous on the graph of $L : \mathcal{D}(L)\subset L^2\rightarrow L^2$, such that $\Phi$ vanishes on the compactly supported $C^{\infty}$ functions on $(a,b)$. In this case, the boundary functionals form a $4$ dimensional subspace spanned by the limits of $f,f'$ at $a,b$, and these limits can be shown to exist knowing only a formulation in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a function, then $f$ is called differentiable in $a$ if

$ \lim_{x \to a+0} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists

and $f$ is called differentiable in $b$ if

$ \lim_{x \to b-0} \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$ exists.